# How can I get result item count in sql db?

Tags: java, count, textfield

I am trying to find `john` in `name` column in database but I am not able to.

What I am trying is as follows :

```
String st="SELECT name FROM mytable";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(st);
int icount = 0 ;
if (rs.equals("john")) {
    while (rs.next()) { 
        icount++;
    }
}
jtext1.setText(String.valueOf(icount));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to check if `ResultSet` object is equal to `john` string - ofc it's always `false`. You need something like this:

```
String query = "SELECT name FROM mytable";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int johnCount = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    if ("john".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
        johnCount++;
    }
}
```

Note `equalsIgnoreCase` method - I think it's more appropriate in your case. Don't forget to close your `ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection` in `finally` block or use `try-with-resources`.

But if you want to count Johns in your table, it's better just to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE name = 'john'` actually. Note that this is case-sensitive condition in query.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way....

```
int count = 0;
String query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS rCount FROM myTable "
             + "WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('JOHN');" 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) { count = rs.getInt("rCount"); }
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String st="SELECT name FROM mytable";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(st);
int icount = 0 ;
while (rs.next()) { 
    if (rs.getString("name").equals("john")) {
        icount++;
    }
}
jtext1.setText(String.valueOf(icount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
while(rs.next()){
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    if("john".equals(name))
        icount++;
}
jtext1.setText(String.valueOf(icount));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go over each row with

```
while (rs.next) {....
```

And you need to get the value out to compare like this

```
String name = rs.getString(1);
If (name.equals("john")) {....
```

The other option is to change the quest to do the count this is more efficient.

```
select count(name) from myTable where name = 'john';
```

Comment: It should be rs.getString(1) if you're interested in getting the first column.

Comment: No problem if you like the answer vote it up :)